# How to get shortest route in google Directions API instead of Fastest?

Tags: android, google-maps, routes, google-directions-api

I'm trying to Draw a route with origin and destinations including Waypoints. When I set optimized parameter as true, it returns me the result in form of fastest instead of shortest. I tried alternatives:true but no change in response,

Request is like this:- 
[Check this link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?Alternatives:true&origin=17.23968,78.47489&destination=17.23968,78.47489&waypoints=optimize:false%7C17.441855,78.408248%7C17.438244,78.444335%7C17.436574,78.400866%7C17.435366,78.411252%7C17.433647,78.427328)

Kindly note that am working for android so will be using Android Api V2. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: [what about this answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36985487/4537906)

Comment: Thanks for it, it is actually for Directions JSP API but it gave me the hint to reach my answer.

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594291/how-do-we-get-the-shortest-distance-route-from-point-a-to-b-by-default-from-goog), it might help you also.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is not currently a way to have the API return the absolute shortest route in all situations.

One option you have to get shorter routes rather than the fastest route is to have the API return alternative routes with the alternatives parameter, [1]. You can then examine the results and select the one with the shortest distance. This may not provide the absolute shortest route, but will give you a list of possible routes from which to select the shortest.

[1] https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#RequestParameters

I hope this information answers your question.

Comment: you can use traffic_mode and set to optimistic https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#StatusCodes